# Template in C++ - Why explicit function not getting called?

Tags: c++, templates

Below I am giving two programs and their outputs.

code1:

```
   #include<iostream>
    using namespace std;

    template <class X,class Y> X sumargs(X a,Y b)
    {
        cout<<"\nThe sum is :" << a+b; 

    }

    int sumargs(int a,char b)
    {
      cout<<"\nThis works\n";
      return 1;
    }

    int main()
    {

        sumargs<int>(1,2);
        sumargs<char>(4,9.0);
        sumargs<double>('d',8);
        sumargs(7,'a');
        return 0;
    }
```

output 1:

```
The sum is :3
The sum is :13
The sum is :108
This works
```

code 2:

```
#include<iostream>
using namespace std;

template <class X,class Y> X sumargs(X a,Y b)
{
    cout<<"\nThe sum is :" << a+b; 

}

int sumargs(int a,char b)
{
  cout<<"\nThis works\n";
  return 1;
}

int main()
{

    sumargs<int>(1,2);
    sumargs<char>(4,9.0);
    sumargs<double>('d',8);
    sumargs<int>(7,'a');
    return 0;
}
```

output 2:

```
The sum is :3
The sum is :13
The sum is :108
The sum is :104
```

Why is **sumargs(7,'a');** in the **code 2** not calling the explicitly overloaded version of the function?

Comment: Your first `sumargs` shouldn't even compile; it never returns a value despite claiming that it does.

Comment: @SebastianRedl: Why doesn't it detect the error? I am using g++ compiler.

Comment: Use -Wall -Werror. g++ is annoyingly lenient sometimes.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Here:

```
sumargs<int>(7,'a');
//     ^^^^^
```

You are specifying template arguments *explicitly*. Since you are explicitly specifying template arguments, the compiler will only consider function *templates* to resolve the call.

Your overload is not a template, and non-templates do not accept template arguments. Therefore, the compiler will not consider it.

Comment: isn't that <int> for return type?

Comment: @Inquisitive: Yes, but it is still a template argument. Non-templates do not have template arguments. Since you are using them, only function templates are considered by the compiler

Answer (score 2):

In addition to Andy Prowl's answer, note that you can use template specialization for what you are doing:

```
template<>
int sumargs<int,char>(int a,char b)
{
  cout<<"\nThis works\n";
  return 1;
}
```

Comment: I was late :) I will delete mine

Answer (score 2):

you should used

```
template <>
int sumargs<int,char>(int a,char b)
{
   cout<<"\nThis works\n";
   return 1;
}
```

try special functions template